# Update information simultaneously

Tags: php, mysql

Why does not my code update?
and echo no!

```
$sql_updata1 = "UPDATE information_user SET invitation = '1' WHERE information_user.id = '$ID_Invitation'; UPDATE information_user SET valid = '$num_Invitation '+' $number_userInvitation' WHERE information_user.id = '$ID_Invitation'; UPDATE information_user SET valid = '$num_Caller '+' $number_userCaller' WHERE information_user.id = '$id_user_invitation';";

if ((mysqli_query($con, $sql_updata1)){
    echo "ok";
} else {
    echo "no";
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this with multiple queries? You can put multiple assignment in a single `UPDATE`. `SET invitation = 1, valid = '$num_Invitations' + $number_userInvitation, ...`

Comment: @Barmar, I've re-opened it, would you post an answer suggesting how it could be done - thanks.

Comment: you can use MySQL multi-query to execute multiple statements.

Comment: I'm actually in the API
When some of the bets are checked and arrived here, I want to add the invitations 5 to invite and invite 3 to invite number 1 that can no longer invite anyone.
If you have a better solution, thank you for saying that

Comment: Just a bit of advice - if at all possible you should switch from mysqli to PDO https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php. It is more secure.

Comment: See also: [PHP PDO MySQL Transaction code structure](//stackoverflow.com/q/8618618)

Comment: Having that query on one line where you have to scroll back and forth to even begin to see what you're doing is a huge hassle here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as a single query. Make the `WHERE` clause select both the caller and callee. You can assign to multiple columns in the `SET` clause, and you can use `IF` or `CASE` to make the value that you assign dependent on the `id` of the row you're processing.

```
$sql_updata1 = "
    UPDATE information_user 
    SET invitation = IF(id = '$ID_Invitation', '1', invitation)
        valid = IF(id = '$ID_Invitation', 
                    $num_Invitation + $number_userInvitation, 
                    $num_Caller + $number_userCaller)
    WHERE id IN ('$ID_Invitation', '$id_user_invitation')";
```